# importing own files in python

Tags: python-3.x, import

I am new in python but I am familiar with C++.
I wanted to keep my class definition and functions in separate file.
I used

> import filename

but while I was calling functions of imported file, I got error i.e.
function not defined. Do we need include guards or something?

Comment: I'm *guessing* that `from filename import *` would solve your problem, but that's bad practice and anyway you should provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
filename.function()
```

Alternatively, you can replace your import statement:

```
from filename import function, function2
```

More information in the [reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html).